# UITextField check empty after editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

So I have next problem [UITextField strange behavior when delete symbol in first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396795/uitextfield-strange-behavior-when-delete-symbol-in-first-time) and I see next decision: check after first editing textfield text and replace it if empty. How can I check it, no one delegate method cann't help me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's matters what you need.

Most simplest way to check if `UITextField` is empty you can use this:

```
if (textField.text.length == 0) {
    // textField is empty
}
```

but it will fail if user will add whitespace.. so to solve this:

```
NSString *value = [textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

if(value.length == 0) {
    // textField is empty
}
```

---

Other solution:

```
if([textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    // textField is empty
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Add action to your textfield which will be called every time textfield did change:

```
// Add this for example in ViewDidLoad:
[textfieldOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

And method:

```
- (void)textFieldChanged:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.text.length == 0) {
        textField.text = @"Changed text to this!";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I understand how to check it, but I want to know when I can check it and how? While editing of textfield in progress. So I delete character and how I check that textfield become empty>

Comment: @user2213271 You need to check it in `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` textField's delegate with writted above checks.

Comment: you don't understand me =( When I try to delete last character - it delete all field, so I need check after this delegate method ended

Comment: @user2213271 take a look at my updated answer it should do it what You need.

Comment: On swift, just type

    - if (textField.text.isEmpty) {
       // Alert
    }